# Call the method of a component inside another component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react native. I have two components(screen A and screen B) as below. I need to call the  `_showModalHistory` method of screen B inside screen A. 
Here is the code of screen A (Component A):

```
 import B from './B.js';

    class A extends Component {
      render() {
            return (
                this.refs.B._showModalHistory();
                  );
              }
        }
```

In screen B (Component B) also I have the following code:

```
      export default class B extends Component {

          constructor(props) {
                super();
                this.subscription = 0;
                this.state = {
                };
                changePage = props.cb;

                this.state = {
                  isModalVisible: false,
                  isModalVisibleHistory: false,
                };
            }

          _showModalHistory = () => this.setState({ isModalVisibleHistory: true });

          render() {
                return (
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisibleHistory}>
            <View style={styles.contianer}>
            <History></History>
            </View>
            </Modal>
    );}
    }
```

I tried to use ref in screen A, in order to reach the method of screen B but, it shows me a  the error of "

> Cannot read properity '_showModalHistory' of undefine".

Could you please check what is wrong with my code? should I add anything to perform the ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first render your `B` component inside `A`. Then set the ref as shown below.

```
 class A extends Component {

      // Some on click listener.

      onClick() {
         this.B._showModalHistory();
      }


      render() {
            return (
                <B ref={component => { this.B = component; }} />
            );
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is onClick() here?

Comment: Any method inside `A` that you'll want to call inside `A` when you want to call `_showModalHistory` method of `B`.

Comment: Thanks but, it shows me the error of "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag"

Comment: Enclose all the JSX in the render method of `A` within a root `<View></View>`.

Comment: I have already put <View></View> but, it gave me the same error.  Do you to see the whole code?

Comment: I have added to your answer by mistake sorry.

Comment: Can you delete it from your answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aha! I found it. You're returning two components together side by side from your render method of `A`. `<View>` with `<StyleProvider>`. You cannot do that.
Return only one parent component. 
Either `<View>Everything</View>` or `<StyleProvider>Everything</StyleProvider>` like so. Did you understand?

Comment: The App came up but, it shows a warning and it dose't work. it tells "Faild prop type" invalid prop' children' of type 'array' supplied to styleProvider, except a a single reactElement".

Comment: Yes, I believe that's because `<StyleProvider>` also expects a single component as a child and not many. In your case `StyleProvider` has two children `<View>` and `<Container>` side by side. Wrap `<Container>` and `<SostaInCorso_yellow_5A>` inside `<View>` and put that `<View>` inside `<StyleProvider>` as it's only child.

Comment: Please also don't use `ref={this.ref}` for storing refs as that can cause problems. Use the syntax I've shown in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158878/discussion-between-queen-and-mustansir-zia).